# Dynamic memory and classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use `delete[]` in the destructor to delete a pointer that was created. I'm getting garbage as a result when using `delete[] string;`. Without `delete`, my code comes out right:

```
class test
{
public:
    test operator=(char* tests)
    {
        this->string = tests;
        return *this;
    }

    int starlen()
    {
        i = 0;
        while (this->string[i] != '\0')
            i++;

        return i;
    }

    test operator+(test& tests)
    {
        a = strlen(this->string);
        b = strlen(tests.string);

        ptr = this->string;
        ptr2 = tests.string;

        for (int i = a; i < a + b; i++)
        {
            *(ptr + i) = *(ptr2 + i - a);
        }

        ptr[a + b] = '\0';
        return ptr;
    }

    void printit()
    {
        cout << string;
    }

    test()
    {
        string = 0;
    }

    test(char* ptr)
    {
        string = new char[10];
        strcpy(string, ptr);
    }

    ~test()
    {
        //delete[] string; ????
    }

public:
    char* string;
    int a;
    int b;
    char* ptr;
    char* ptr2;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    test t1("book");
    test t2("shelf");
    test t3;
    t3 = t1 + t2;
    cout << t3.starlen() << endl;

    t3.printit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please remove all the superfluous empty lines from your code.

Comment: what if someone uses the constructor without any arguments? then you'd `delete[] 0`, and that must go wrong. Also, what does "getting garbage" mean? This question is not well explained.

Comment: Did you try using debugger?

Comment: @MarcusMüller You don't need null-check for delete. Have a look at [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete): _In all cases, if ptr is a null pointer, the standard library deallocation functions do nothing._

Comment: online sample for testing. if poosible, please, add to the question http://cpp.sh/7epdv

Answer (score 3):

Your destructor fails because you are not following the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) correctly:

> The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ (prior to C++11) that claims that if a class defines one (or more) of the following it should probably explicitly define all three:
>
> - destructor
> - **copy constructor**
> - **copy assignment operator**

1. your class is **missing a copy constructor** that accepts a `test` object as input.  You have a *converting constructor* that accepts a `char*` as input, but if that input is more than 9 characters than you will trash surrounding memory while copying characters.
2. your class is **missing a copy assignment operator** that accepts a `test` object as input.  You have a *converting assignment operator* that accepts a `char*` as input, but it is taking *ownership* of that `char*` instead of making a *copy* of the character data, and it is leaking the previously allocated `string` buffer.  And worse, it is returning a *copy* of the `test` object that is being modified, instead of returning a *reference* to the object, and that copy does not work correctly because of your missing *copy constructor*.  So you end up with multiple `test` objects that are pointing to the same `string` buffer in memory, so you will have destructors calling `delete[]` on the same memory too many times.

Also, your `operator+` is implemented incorrectly as well.  It returns a new `test` object, but it is not allocating new memory that accounts for the total length of the two source strings.  You are simply copying character data from the right-hand `test` object directly into the `char*` string of the left-hand `test` object without expanding it first.  So you are trashing surrounding memory.  This `operator+` is supposed to return a new `test` object that is a *copy* of the input strings concatenated together without modifying either of the source strings at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class test
{
public:
    // default constructor
    test()
        : string(0)
    {
    }

    // copy constructor
    test(const test &src)
        : string(new char[src.starlen()+1])
    {
        strcpy(string, src.string);
    }

    // converting constructor
    test(const char* src)
        : string(new char[strlen(src)+1])
    {
        strcpy(string, src);
    }

    // destructor
    ~test()
    {
        delete[] string;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    test& operator=(const test &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
            std::swap(string, test(rhs).string);
        return *this;
    }

    // converting assignment operator
    test& operator=(const char *rhs)
    {
        std::swap(string, test(rhs).string);
        return *this;
    }

    int starlen() const
    {
        return strlen(string);
    }

    test operator+(const test& rhs) const
    {
        int a = starlen();
        int b = rhs.starlen();

        test ret;
        ret.string = new char[a+b+1];
        strcpy(ret.string, string);
        strcpy(ret.string+a, rhs.string);

        return ret;
    }

    void printit() const
    {
        std::cout << string;
    }

private:
    char* string;
};

int main()
{
    test t1("book");
    test t2("shelf");
    test t3;
    t3 = t1 + t2;
    cout << t3.starlen() << endl;

    t3.printit();

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you should also follow the [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Five) as well:

> With the advent of C++11 the rule of three can be broadened to the rule of five as C++11 implements move semantics, allowing destination objects to grab (or steal) data from temporary objects. The following example also shows the new moving members: move constructor and move assignment operator. Consequently, for the rule of five we have the following special members:
>
> - destructor
> - copy constructor
> - **move constructor**
> - copy assignment operator
> - **move assignment operator**

```
class test
{
public:
    // default constructor
    test()
        : string(0)
    {
    }

    // copy constructor
    test(const test &src)
        : string(new char[src.starlen()+1])
    {
        strcpy(string, src.string);
    }

    // converting constructor
    test(const char* src)
        : string(new char[strlen(src)+1])
    {
        strcpy(string, src);
    }

    // move constructor
    test(test &&src)
        : string(0)
    {
        std::swap(string, src.string);
    }

    // destructor
    ~test()
    {
        delete[] string;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    test& operator=(const test &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
            std::swap(string, test(rhs).string);
        return *this;
    }

    // converting assignment operator
    test& operator=(const char *rhs)
    {
        std::swap(string, test(rhs).string);
        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator
    test& operator=(test &&rhs)
    {
        std::swap(string, rhs.string);
        return *this;
    }

    int starlen() const
    {
        return strlen(string);
    }

    test operator+(const test& rhs) const
    {
        int a = starlen();
        int b = rhs.starlen();

        test ret;
        ret.string = new char[a+b+1];
        strcpy(ret.string, string);
        strcpy(ret.string+a, rhs.string);

        return ret;
    }

    void printit() const
    {
        std::cout << string;
    }

private:
    char* string;
};
```

That being said, this is probably just a learning exercise in how to write a custom string class.  However, the C++ standard defines a `std::string` class, you should use it instead.  If you want your own class, you can delegate to `std::string`, let the compiler and STL do the heavy work for you:

```
class test
{
public:
    // default constructor
    test()
    {
    }

    // copy constructor
    test(const test &src)
        : str(src.str)
    {
    }

    // converting constructor
    test(const std::string &src)
        : str(src)
    {
    }

    // move constructor
    test(test &&src)
        : str(std::move(src.str))
    {
    }

    int starlen() const
    {
        return str.length();
    }

    test operator+(const test& rhs) const
    {
        return str + rhs.str;
    }

    void printit() const
    {
        std::cout << str;
    }

private:
    std::string str;
};
```

Comment: Ah, the rule of 3 has made an appearance yet again!

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It lurks ever at the edge of your vision, awaiting the opportunity to strike.

Answer (score 0):

Who's responsibility is it to delete the internal string?  I notice you are assigning the string's memory into t3 with no constructor, then calling a destructor on probably the same memory address twice.  Also, your operator +, the coping is very likely going to write passed the end of the array it is being assigned back into.  You at the very least should have a strlen() end check there to prevent that from occuring.  If you have corrupted your buffer, then any call to delete[] will complain due to memory overwrites on the heap.

Please see Remy's answer for a much better solution that properly handles the (quite complex) nature of string manipulation and memory allocation issues.  That answer is even exception safe from what I can see.